# How to make user profiles searchable and filterable by multiple fields in the context of a job site

Tags: users, search

I'm currently in the process of developing a job search site hopefully with these abilities for users of the site:

Job seekers can search for and filter jobs. I'm on my way with this so no problem here.

However what I would like to do is create users searchable for employers. So users can sign up and fill in a number of fields, expertise, CV, skills or whatever else...

Then I want users with paid employer accounts to be able to search and filter employees by these fields.

I'm fairly new to Drupal and I was wondering how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to use views here.

When you create your view, make sure you use Users and not Content. See screenshot. Once you do this you can set up and expose all the filters you need to allow searching, etc.

[image]